# Get a list of chats "like a messanger"

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, model

I have problem with my code. I want to get unique users/conversations.
My database look like this

```
ID| FROM | TO | MESSAGE
```

I want to get unique list of this chats, but when i have (1,2) (2,1) when someone answer i have doubled records.

```
Message::select('from','to','message','created_at')->latest()->where('from',Auth::id())->orWhere('to',Auth::id())->with('from','to')->distinct('from','to')->get()
```

Comment: What is `distinct('from','to')` supposed to do? The [`distinct()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L352)  method doesn't have any parameters.

Comment: If user send more than one message i will have it all. I want only one latest.

Comment: If 1 sends message to 2 (1,2) and 2 sends message to 1(2,1) and there can be multiple messages too. You want to consider it as one pair (1,2) and want the latest message only?

Comment: I want to get one pair with no doubled pairs. So i can render chats with it. With latest message.

Comment: I can do it with js, but i want this to be clear and optimal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually seem to want is a list of users with which your currently authenticated user has had a conversation previously. You can get this users with the following query:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$authId = auth()->id();

$users = User::query()
    ->whereHas('messages', function (Builder $query) use ($authId) {
        $query->where('from', $authId)
            ->orWhere('to', $authId);
    })
    ->get();
```

You then probably want to show a preview of the conversation for each user, most likely with the latest message as you described. Retrieving this messages can be tricky, but with the help of a sub query and a special relation, it is quite simple.

First, we need to extend our user query to also include the id of the latest message:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder as QueryBuilder;

$authId = auth()->id();

$users = User::query()
    ->whereHas('messages', function (Builder $query) use ($authId) {
        $query->where('from', $authId)
            ->orWhere('to', $authId);
    })
    ->where('id', '!=', $authId)
    ->select()
    ->selectSub(function (QueryBuilder $query) use ($authId) {
        $query->from('messages')
            ->where(function (QueryBuilder $query) use ($authId) {
                $query->whereColumn('messages.from', 'users.id')
                    ->where('messages.to', $authId);
            })
            ->orWhere(function (QueryBuilder $query) use ($authId) {
                $query->whereColumn('messages.to', 'users.id')
                    ->where('messages.from', $authId);
            })
            ->orderByDesc('created_at')
            ->limit(1)
            ->select('id');
    }, 'last_message_id')
    ->get();
```

Then, we simply define a `HasOne` relation for the latest message on the user model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function lastMessage(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Message::class, 'id', 'last_message_id');
    }
}
```

Now, all we have to do is add `->with('lastMessage')` to our query and we will be able to iterate our users with the last message from or to our currently authenticated user.

Comment: I think i do something wrong, when i have messages (1,2) (2,1) User_1 => User_2 and User_2 => User_1 this query give me User_2 and Me User_1

Comment: When i add @if($message->id !==auth()->id) Chat_here @endif all work ok. But i dont want to do this that way.

Comment: You sure that your test data contains the correct ids? The last if is clearly wrong . Think about it.

Comment: Now i have (1,2) (2,1) and (1,3). Messages relation in user look like this: return $this->hasMany('App\Message','to','id'); But stil my problem exist

Comment: I updated the query, some essential `where` parts were missing for the `last_message_id`. Sorry.

Comment: Still the same. I post answer so u can better understand what is on.

Comment: Also when someone write me message, and i dont write him back, my user show on chats list.

Answer (score 0):

On this moment i figure somethink like this. And this work. If someone have better solution.

```
 $authId = auth()->id();

    $users =
        User::query()->whereHas('messages_from', function (Builder $query) use ($authId) {
            $query->where('from', $authId)
                ->orWhere('to', $authId);
        })->where('id', '!=', $authId)
        ->orwhereHas('messages_to', function (Builder $query) use ($authId) {
        $query->where('from', $authId)
            ->orWhere('to', $authId);
    })
        ->where('id', '!=', $authId)
        ->select()
        ->selectSub(function (QueryBuilder $query) use ($authId) {
            $query->from('messages')
                ->where(function (QueryBuilder $query) use ($authId) {
                    $query->whereColumn('messages.from', 'users.id')
                        ->where('messages.to', $authId);
                })
                ->orWhere(function (QueryBuilder $query) use ($authId) {
                    $query->whereColumn('messages.to', 'users.id')
                        ->where('messages.from', $authId);
                })
                ->orderByDesc('created_at')
                ->limit(1)
                ->select('message');
        }, 'message')
        ->get();
    return $users->jsonSerialize();
```

User.php

```
     public function messages_from(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\Message','from','id');
        }
        public function messages_to(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\Message','to','id');
        }
```